# What are pressures, air-flow rates and ground clearance of some real-life hovercraft?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm trying to get a feel for the real life behavior of hover craft air cushions and the associated power consumption. To get a feel for relevant numbers, I'd like to know

- actual pressure used to lift said hover craft
- the clearance (average or range) between skirt and water/ground surface
- the air loss through that clearance

One could treat the clearance as a simple slit, however the air flow under a hover craft is more complex that that due to the round shape of the skirt. In practical operation the craft will hover around an equlibirium where the pressure is "weight of hovercraft" / "area under skirt" and the clearance is higher or lower depending on airflow (or the airflow is higher or lower depending on clearance required). An empirical formula for the relationship between pressure, clearance, skirt length and air flow would be even better, but real life numbers for one situation are ok.

Comment: Have you checked out the ones that were in service from Dover?

Comment: @SolarMike I've mostly hunted around wikipedia, but didnt find datasheets or the links to datasheets there

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SR.N4

Comment: Google search term: "hovercraft design"...

Comment: From the SR.N4 page I can find the the pressure must be near a range ob 1.8 - 2.4 kPa, depending on build, no info on air flow or clearance. But you are right that searching off wikipedia is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I cannot assist you with explicit formulas myself, I would like to make you aware of the book [*Theory and Design of Air Cushion Craft* by Liang Yun, Alan Bliault](https://books.google.no/books?id=aJT0gK710LwC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is available (with limitations) on Google Books. In particular, I would suggest the chapters; *[2] Air cushion theory* and *[12] Lift system design*.

Sure, some pages are not included in the preview, but considering the overall quality of the book, I find this a small price to pay. Having had a look at it myself, I also believe it will be of great assistance, whatever expertise you currently possess in the field of air cushion vehicles.